# How to revoke all roles from a schema in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, permissions

How can I revoke all roles (or all roles except the creator of the schema) from a specific schema in Postgres 14?

I have an ETL process that periodically dynamically creates a Postgres schema and authorizes roles on it based on a steering table. The authorizations could change, so I want to drop all roles every time, and re-authorize them based on what that table specifies.

Lets say adminalice runs this ETL proces.
I execute this as the adminalice user:

```
CREATE SCHEMA demo_schema AUTHORIZE adminalice;
CREATE ROL johndoe;
CREATE ROL janedoe;
GRANT ALL ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA demo_schema TO johndoe;
GRANT ALL ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA demo_schema TO janedoe;
```

Now I would like to revoke all the roles I granted to the demo_schema.
However, the script that executes this (as adminalice) does not know which roles exists, and as a precaution I want to drop all roles always.

I thought I could do this by issuing a:

```
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA demo_schema FROM PUBLIC;
```

Postgres 14 says:

```
REVOKE [ GRANT OPTION FOR ]
    { { CREATE | USAGE } [, ...] | ALL [ PRIVILEGES ] }
    ON SCHEMA schema_name [, ...]
    FROM role_specification [, ...]
    [ GRANTED BY role_specification ]
    [ CASCADE | RESTRICT ]

where role_specification can be:

    [ GROUP ] role_name
  | PUBLIC
  | CURRENT_ROLE
  | CURRENT_USER
  | SESSION_USER
```

> The REVOKE command revokes previously granted privileges from one or
> more roles. The key word PUBLIC refers to the implicitly defined group
> of all roles.

Ideally adminalice retains her authorization (I have the impression that this is possible), but this is not very important as I can simply issue a fresh authorization after the drop of all roles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no single statement for that. You have to do that per role. In your example, you could drop the roles and all their privileges with

```
DROP OWNED BY johndoe;
DROP ROLE johndoe;
DROP OWNED BY janedoe;
DROP ROLE janedoe;
```

That will only work if the roles have no privileges or objects in any other database.